# How to avoid event from div below object?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, event-bubbling

I have this code:

```
<div style="width:200px;height:100px;border:solid 1px" onclick="alert(1)">
  Title
  <br />
  Subtitle
  <div style="float:right">
  <input type="checkbox" />
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to redirect the user to a url when he clicks on the div (where the alert is now) but I want to allow the user with functionality when he clicks on the checkbox.

Is it possible to allow the checkbox to be clicked and change status without invoking the `alert(1)` from the div below ?

Comment: You can check also if(event.srcElement == this) alert(1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use event.stopPropagation(); function. This function prevents further propagation of the current event in the capturing and bubbling phases.

```
<div style="width:200px;height:100px;border:solid 1px" onclick="alert(1)">
Title
<br />
Subtitle
<div style="float:right">
<input type="checkbox" onclick="onCheckBoxCicked(event)"/>
</div>
```

```
 function onCheckBoxCicked(event) {
        alert(2)
        event.stopPropagation();
    };
```

Comment: thank you, does it have side effects or it's safe ?

Comment: It is a standard way of how you can stop an event from bubbling in a case when you have click listener for parent and child divs.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use **[`stopPropagation()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)** on the `checkbox` click event handler, so the click of the checkbox won't trigger the click of its parents divs:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="avoidAlert(event)" />
```

**JS:**

```
function avoidAlert(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
}
```

```js
function avoidAlert(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
}
```

```html
<div style="width:200px;height:100px;border:solid 1px" onclick="alert(1)">
  Title
  <br /> Subtitle
  <div style="float:right">
    <input type="checkbox" onclick="avoidAlert(event)" />
  </div>
</div>
```

[MDN Ref for **`stopPropagation()` method**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation):

> The `stopPropagation()` method of the Event interface prevents further propagation of the current event in the capturing and bubbling phases.

Answer (score 0):

You could either try `event.stopPropagation()` inside an extra event handler on the checkbox, or simply check inside the div's event handler if the target of the click has been the checkbox:

```js
var theDiv = document.querySelector('.outer'),
    theCheckbox = document.querySelector('input');

theDiv.addEventListener('click', divClicked);
    
function divClicked(e) {
  if (e.target !== theCheckbox) {
    alert('You clicked the div!');
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="outer" style="width:200px;height:100px;border:solid 1px">
  Title
  <br />
  Subtitle
  <div style="float:right">
  <input type="checkbox" />
  </div>
</div>
```